# MUI TimePicker and StaticDatePicker input datatypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im having issues setting the correct datatypes in MUI TimePicker and StaticDatePicker (https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/).

I have tried a few iterations of date objects (dayjs and moment) and even strings. I am able to display the time using the 'value' prop when I use the moment library, but I know there is an issue in the backend because onSubmit it doesnt recognize that the field is populated (unless I re-populate and even if I do it doesnt read the date correctly). Similarly, I am only able to type in TimePicker and cannot select from the dropdown using moment. Here is a snippet of my code, all help would be appreciated - been quite the journey.

```
  const [bookingDate, setBookingDate] = useState(dayjs(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)))
  const [bookingTime, setBookingTime] = useState(moment('20:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss'))

  const initialValues = {
    booking_date: bookingDate,
    booking_time: bookingTime,
  }

 const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    var data = {
      booking_date: dayjs(event.booking_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      booking_time: dayjs(event.booking_time).format('HH:mm'),
    }
    async function doSubmit() {
      await axios.post(....)
    }
    doSubmit()
  }

return (
 <>
 <Formik  initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          {({ errors, touched, setFieldValue, values }) => {
            return (
   <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
     <Field
      as={StaticDatePicker}
      id='booking_date'
      name='booking_date'
      value={bookingDate}
      onChange={(newValue) => setFieldValue('booking_date', handleDateChange(newValue))}
      label='Booking date'
      />
      <Field
       as={TimePicker}
       id='booking_time'
       name='booking_time'
       value={moment(initialValues.booking_time, 'HH:mm:ss')}
       onChange={(newValue) => {
       setFieldValue('booking_time', handleTimeChange(newValue))
       }}
       label='Desired table time'
       />
   </LocalizationProvider>
 </Formik>
</>
```

In the code snipped above, I am showing a few different ways I have tried to input dates.